# one would expect the doctor to retire

Tags: dangling-participles

1. *After spending so many years working in hospitals, one would expect the doctor **to have retired***.
2. *After spending so many years working in hospitals, one would expect the doctor **to retire***.

Q1) Do they both mean the same?

Q2) What is the subject of "spending". Is it "one" or is it "the doctor"? In other words, is this a case of "dangling modifier"?

Comment: (1) is a perfect infinitive.  It implies not only (2) but that the doctor has not retired yet. I would tend to read "the doctor" as the subject of "spending" in both cases, though the sentences are poorly constructed.  I find it harder to read "one" as its subject than personal pronouns like "I", "she" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meanings are as follows but the words in bold need not be said/written, as they are implied in  the tense of the verb

1. After spending so many years working in hospitals, one would expect the doctor to have **already** retired.
2. After spending so many years working in hospitals, one would expect the doctor to retire **at sometime between now and the near future**."

> Q2) What is the subject of "spending".

Spending does not have a clear subject because you have not given sufficient context.

Comment: In **both** 1) and 2), does the "after..." clause mean the doctor has **already** spent many years working...?

Comment: @Mr.X *clause mean the doctor has already spent many years working...?* Please read my answer. *Spending does not have a clear subject because you have not given sufficient context.* **It is not possible to say who** has spent *"so many years working in hospitals,"*

Comment: I think the grammatical structure tends to imply that it is "one" that has spent many years working in hospitals, but without more context that doesn't make sense semantically because it doesn't explain at all why the doctor might be expected to retire. Conversely if we interpret it to mean that it's the doctor who spent those years then that completely explains why they might be expected to retire. So yes, as written it's open to interpretation, but if you put a gun to my head and made me choose a meaning I know which I'd opt for.

Comment: @Mr.X *context would decide the subject of "spending"* - Exactly.

Comment: @Greybeard, You say, "*Spending does not have a clear subject because you have not given sufficient context*" in other words, context would decide the subject of "spending". My question: Do you mean the concept of "dangling modifiers" is not so important because context could almost always clear up the issue?

Comment: No I do not mean *the concept of "dangling modifiers" is not so important*. A dangling modifier, by definition, is ambiguous regardless of context. Dangling modifiers cease to be dangling modifiers when the subject becomes clear. See Purdue Owl at https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/dangling_modifiers_and_how_to_correct_them.html

Comment: What if I add some more context or a sentence, for example: is the sentence below possible?-----

*My friend John is a doctor working in hospitals. After **spending** years working in hospitals, one would expect **him** to have retired.*